# NoClassDefFoundError while running a java program in terminal from IDE

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I am having trouble running a java program that works fine in the IntelliJ IDEA ide. The error I get when I run the same code (after removing the package ..) as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fcrypt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fcrypt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

All I'm doing in the main method is creating an instance of the main class and calling the several methods. The code with just the headers and the main method as below

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Aditya Rao on 05/02/14.
 */
public class fcrypt {
    private static final String RSA_NONE_PKCS1PADDING = "RSA/None/PKCS1Padding";

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    ....

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 5) {
            System.out.print("Invalid parameters. ");
            printUsage();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (!(args[0].equals("-e") | args[0].equals("-d"))) {
            System.out.print("Please specify usage. ");
            printUsage();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        fcrypt f = new fcrypt();

        String[] inputs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);
        if (args[0].equals("-e"))
            f.encryptAndSign(inputs);
        else
            f.verifyAndDecrypt(inputs);
    }
 }
```

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT** I compile and run this program with the following commands

```
javac -cp libs/bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar fcrypt.java
java -cp libs/bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar fcrypt <args>
```

Comment: Sounds like a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java) issue.  Make sure you pass the classpath to when you execute your jar.  IntelliJ is probably appending this automatically. What is the exact commandline that intellij is executing? It should say in a little terminal prompt when you run the app

Comment: I have the bouncycastle jar, but I have added the appropriate classpaths for compiling and running the program. I have edited the question with the commands.

Comment: Does fcrypt have a constructor? What happens if you remove         fcrypt f = new fcrypt(); from inside main? Does the error change?

Comment: Interesting, I thought it was because of this line. Now I get the same error after I remove that line. So its a classpath issue, but does it have anything to do with the lib I've included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add working directory denoted as `.` to the class path as fcrypt.class is located there.

Syntax for Unix:

```
java -cp ".:libs/bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar" fcrypt
```

note elements are separated with `:`.

Syntax for Windows:

```
java -cp ".;libs/bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar" fcrypt
```

note elements are separated with `;`.

Java code style suggests class names to start with a capital letter. So it should be `class FCrypt` defined in `FCrypt.java`.