# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with jar file in terminal

Tags: java, exception

In Eclipse, I wrote a Java class `Test` with a `main()` function.
The project in which is defined the class, I added the jar file `bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar` (I am using the library BouncyCastle).

In Eclipse, there is no problem and my program runs normally. But when I try to do it in a terminal, I get an exception.

After checking SO I found a similar post: [NoClassDefFoundError while running a java program in terminal from IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655358/noclassdeffounderror-while-running-a-java-program-in-terminal-from-ide) but the solution given doesn't work.

To illustrate my case, in the directory `C:\Docs\workspace\Terminal\bin\` I have the file `Test.class`.  If I run `java Test` I get     `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECFieldElement`.

If I run `java -cp bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar Test` (I put the `.jar` in the same directory to simplify) I get `Error: Could not find or load main class Test` so it seems that the dependency error is solved but another one occurs.

What am I doing wrong? Just to give the structure of my `.java` file:

```
import java.io.*;
   ...
public class Test {

    ... local methods ...

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you forgot to include current path "."

```
 java -cp ".;bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar" Test
```

Hope it help